# Do not execute postinstall when installing package as dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a package `x` that has postinstall script. During development I used it to do some tasks that are needed during development of this package.

Now I've published this package. When installing it with `npm install` (`x` is listed as dependency in package.json) I don't want to execute postinstall task and this is not needed for package to be used as runtime dependency.

Is is possible to achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried installing package `x` globally?

Comment: It's not the case, package is runtime dependency of web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable all scripts with `--ignore-scripts`

Comment: how about for single dependency?

Comment: You can only disable all scripts. Not for a single dependency, without changing npm.